# Repeating a function when someone reacts to it

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to make it so when someone reacts to the message with the emoji it repeats the function - trying to find something that works similar to `goto` in batch files

Eg: I type `$randomcar`

Bot sends: `Your chosen car is the bmw!` with the  reaction.  When I press on it it repeats the function again:

Bot sends `Your chosen car is the audi!` with the  reaction which I can press on to once again to repeat the function

```py
@bot.command()
async def randomcar(ctx):
 while True:
   msg = await ctx.send("Your chosen car is the {}!".format(random.choice(cars)))
   await msg.add_reaction("")
   async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
     if msg.reaction=="" and msg.id:
      continue
```

I am getting the error:

```
Syntax error: continue not properly in loop
```

Thanks

Comment: `while True` is not good idea - it may block all code.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: well not sure about the complexity of your case - but maybe worth of thinking of an implementation of observer pattern in python. ^^ Basicly you want to observe the input data and react to it if a certain pattern shows up.

Comment: Sorry im quite a beginner - would you mind explaining that?

Comment: to be a beginner is always the best state of mind for development, for every solution we have to find or develop is new to us. so we always begin to find a good solution for. ^^ coming up with observer pattern as a hardcoded solution would be a bit tricky for your case - even though it's one of the key concepts in some programming languages like java -  so I would recommend to take some research if there is an easier or more appropriate solution for you you already scripted the core concept by waiting for the input to come and afterwards responding to it.

Comment: ok ty for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using recursion:

```py
@bot.command()
async def randomcar(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Your chosen car is the {}!".format(random.choice(cars)))
    # you may need to check if your bot has the "add reactions" permission
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    await bot.wait_for(
        "reaction_add",
        check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji == "" and reaction.message == msg,
    )
    await randomcar(ctx)
```

You could also add a `timeout` after which it will stop repeating:

```py
@bot.command()
async def randomcar(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Your chosen car is the {}!".format(random.choice(cars)))
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    try:
        await bot.wait_for(
            "reaction_add",
            timeout=10.0,  # 10 second timeout
            check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji == "" and reaction.message == msg,
        )
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        try:
            await msg.remove_reaction("", bot.user)
        except discord.NotFound:
            pass
    else:
        await randomcar(ctx)
```

Comment: Sorry but would you mind explaining why the second one is better?

Comment: @Pricysquirrl The second option makes it so the bot will stop checking for new reactions after the timeout has expired. So if the command is used many times, the bot does not need to keep checking for new reactions on every message forever.

Comment: oh would this cause performance issues in the future?

Comment: @Pricysquirrl Yes, it probably would.